# flask run keeps referring to python 2.7 even though it's already inside a python3 venv

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I created a virtual environment using the following command:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

I installed all the necessary libraries using pip3 and verified that they all installed properly.
However, every time I try to run the program using the following commands:

```
(venv) $ export FLASK_CONFIG=development
(venv) $ export FLASK_APP=run.py
(venv) $ flask run
```

I always get the following error message:

```
Error: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/harijant/Desktop/python-venv-test/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/Users/harijant/Desktop/python-venv-test/app/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager
ImportError: No module named flask_login
```

As can be seen, it's complaining that python2.7 doesn't have the required libraries which makes sense because I was installing everything using pip3.

I tried to use venv from PyCharm too, and still get the same error.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: after creating the virtual environment, it should be activated with `source env/bin/activate`.  To deactivate type `deactivate` from anywhere (as long as you in the same shell)

Comment: @LucasScott Thanks for the reply! I always do that all the time. I'm sorry if my initial post didn't show that (now it does).

Comment: Any luck? Im stuck with the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Try run these commands and see the output:

```
(venv) $ echo $PATH
(venv) $ which python
(venv) $ which pip
(venv) $ which pip3
```